# making persistent checklist

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to implement a persistent checklist in an android app that keeps the same items checked even if you close the app.

For some reason i can not get it to save. It resets everything as unchecked, even though i have stated for the default for Item 3 to be checked.

Here is my code so far. I am storing the array in sharedprefs, then grabbing them when needed.

Adapter:

```
private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItemClass> {

    private ArrayList<ListItemClass> listItemList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                           ArrayList<ListItemClass> itemList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, itemList);
        this.listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItemClass>();
        this.listItemList.addAll(itemList);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox name;
        TextView desc;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        //Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.checklist_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskListCheckBox);

            holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    ListItemClass item = (ListItemClass) cb.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Toggled: " + cb.getText(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    item.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                    prefsEditor.putString(item.getCode(), item.getString()).commit();
                    ArrayList<ListItemClass> itemList = getArray();
                    listItemList.clear();
                    listItemList.addAll(itemList);

                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.name.setTag(listItemList.get(position));
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListItemClass listItem = listItemList.get(position);
        holder.desc.setText(" (" + listItem.getName() + ")");
        holder.name.setText(listItem.getCode());
        holder.name.setChecked(listItem.isSelected());
        holder.name.setTag(listItem);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

ListItemClass:

```
public class ListItemClass {
    String name = null;
    String desc = null;
    boolean selected = false;

    public ListItemClass(String name, String desc, boolean selected) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.name = code;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.desc = name;
    }
    public String getString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(this.getCode() + ",");
        sb.append(this.getName() + ",");
        sb.append(String.valueOf(this.isSelected()));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

getarray() (to fetch from sharedprefs):

```
private ArrayList<ListItemClass> getArray() {
        ArrayList<ListItemClass> result = new ArrayList<ListItemClass>();

        Map<String, ?> map = prefs.getAll();

        if(!map.isEmpty()) {
            for(Map.Entry<String, ?> entry:map.entrySet()) {
                String itemValue = entry.getValue().toString();
                String key = entry.getKey();
                List<String> list = Arrays.asList(itemValue.split(","));
                result = addCountry(result, key, list.get(1), Boolean.getBoolean(list.get(2)));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

addCountry():

```
private ArrayList<ListItemClass> addCountry(ArrayList<ListItemClass> array, String name, String desc, Boolean selected) {
        ListItemClass country = new ListItemClass(name, desc, selected);
        prefsEditor.putString(country.getCode(), country.getString()).commit();
        array.add(country);
        return array;
    }
```

EDIT: here are where im assigning my shared prefs:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("taskList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
```

Comment: where is you saving state code?

Answer (score 0):

Save the states of checklist in shared preferences.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: `prefsEditor.putString(country.getCode(), country.getString()).commit()` yup im currently trying to attempt using an sqlite database instead ill let you know how that goes